# trying to transfer my bitcoins from my unsynced bitcoin qt wallet to new online wallet by createrawtransaction but it comes with error code

Tags: json-rpc, raw-transaction

it comes up with error

Error:error parsing JSON:
[{txid:my txid,vout:my transaction number},...]

so whats this mean and what can i do to correct it please?
im not very it inclined

cheers :-)

Comment: It appears that your input for the raw transaction was incorrectly formatted in a way that it couldn't be parsed. Without showing us what you actually put in, it's hard to help you. Please edit your question to provide a representative example of what you were inputting (after removing personal information). Then flag for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the data you gave to the command is not valid in some way. You may have  formatted it wrong, or made some other mistake. Without seeing the exact command you used, there is no way for me to know what is wrong.

´createrawtransaction´ is intended for expert users; it is quite possible to  lose your money, permanently, if you make a mistake. If you are "not very IT inclined" then I would strongly recommend not using it. Instead, wait for your Bitcoin Core client to finish syncing, then send your transaction through the regular user interface.

Comment: can you possibly show me a form of command thats correct please?

Comment: @kym: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#simple-raw-transaction